# Function to make the code smaller

Tags: javascript, function, menu, dropdown

Im trying to learn javascript mostly by trial and error, i have created a dropdown menu which probably has ALOT of unnessecary code in it.. How do i create this the right way? any pointer would be appreciated!

JS:

```
function dropdown() {
    var dropdownTrigger = document.getElementById("dd");
    var dropdownTrigger2 = document.getElementById("dd2");
    var dropdownTrigger3 = document.getElementById("dd3");
    var dropdownTrigger4 = document.getElementById("dd4");

    if (dropdownTrigger.style.display == "none") {
        dropdownTrigger.style.display="block";
        dropdownTrigger2.style.display="none";
        dropdownTrigger3.style.display="none";
        dropdownTrigger4.style.display="none";
    }
    else {
        dropdownTrigger.style.display="none";
    }
}
function dropdown2() {
    var dropdownTrigger = document.getElementById("dd");
    var dropdownTrigger2 = document.getElementById("dd2");
    var dropdownTrigger3 = document.getElementById("dd3");
    var dropdownTrigger4 = document.getElementById("dd4");

    if (dropdownTrigger2.style.display == "none") {
        dropdownTrigger.style.display="none";
        dropdownTrigger2.style.display="block";
        dropdownTrigger3.style.display="none";
        dropdownTrigger4.style.display="none";
    }
    else {
        dropdownTrigger2.style.display="none";
    }
}
function dropdown3() {
    var dropdownTrigger = document.getElementById("dd");
    var dropdownTrigger2 = document.getElementById("dd2");
    var dropdownTrigger3 = document.getElementById("dd3");
    var dropdownTrigger4 = document.getElementById("dd4");

    if (dropdownTrigger3.style.display == "none") {
        dropdownTrigger.style.display="none";
        dropdownTrigger2.style.display="none";
        dropdownTrigger3.style.display="block";
        dropdownTrigger4.style.display="none";
    }
    else {
        dropdownTrigger3.style.display="none";
    }
}
function dropdown4() {
    var dropdownTrigger = document.getElementById("dd");
    var dropdownTrigger2 = document.getElementById("dd2");
    var dropdownTrigger3 = document.getElementById("dd3");
    var dropdownTrigger4 = document.getElementById("dd4");

    if (dropdownTrigger4.style.display == "none") {
        dropdownTrigger.style.display="none";
        dropdownTrigger2.style.display="none";
        dropdownTrigger3.style.display="none";
        dropdownTrigger4.style.display="block";
    }
    else {
        dropdownTrigger4.style.display="none";
    }
}

function dropdownAll() {
    var ddaText = document.getElementById("dda");
    var dropdownTrigger1 = document.getElementById("dd");
    var dropdownTrigger2 = document.getElementById("dd2");
    var dropdownTrigger3 = document.getElementById("dd3");
    var dropdownTrigger4 = document.getElementById("dd4");

    if (ddaText.innerHTML == "Open all"){
        ddaText.innerHTML = "Hide all";
        dropdownTrigger1.style.display="block";
        dropdownTrigger2.style.display="block";
        dropdownTrigger3.style.display="block";
        dropdownTrigger4.style.display="block";
    }
    else {
        ddaText.innerHTML = "Open all";
        dropdownTrigger1.style.display="none";
        dropdownTrigger2.style.display="none";
        dropdownTrigger3.style.display="none";
        dropdownTrigger4.style.display="none";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="left-menu">
                    <p>Menu</p>
                    <br>
                    <a href="#" onclick="dropdown()"> +Menu 1</a>
                    <ul id="dd" style="display:none;">
                        <li><a href="#">item 1:1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item 1:2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item 1:3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item 1:4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="#" onclick="dropdown2()"> +Menu 2</a>
                    <ul id="dd2" class="dropdown" style="display:none;">
                        <li><a href="#">item 2:1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item 2:2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item 2:3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item 2:4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="#" onclick="dropdown3()"> +Menu 3</a>
                    <ul id="dd3" class="dropdown" style="display:none;">
                        <li><a href="#">item 3:1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item 3:2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item 3:3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item 3:4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="#" onclick="dropdown4()"> +Menu 4</a>
                    <ul id="dd4" class="dropdown" style="display:none;">
                        <li><a href="#">item 4:1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item 4:2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item 4:3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item 4:4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="#" id="dda" onclick="dropdownAll()">Open all</a>
                </div>
```

is it possible to create function that increases or some kind of loop for this?

Comment: Javascript is not needed - use CSS instead.

Comment: Use common classes and associate elements based on the html structure rather than using a bunch of IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe consider something along the lines of this. This function uses a ternary operator to check if the display value is set to block or none, and switches it accordingly.

```
<button href="#" onclick="toggleDisplay(document.getElementById('dd'))"> +Menu 1</button>
<ul id="dd" style="display:none;">
    <li><a href="#">item 1:1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 1:2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 1:3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 1:4</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
    function toggleDisplay(el){
        el.style.display === 'none' ? // Is it invisible?
        el.style.display = 'block' :  // Then use this
        el.style.display = 'none'     // If not the use this
    }
</script>
```

Edit: Misread; don't use a `<select>` element.

And I will actually better explain what is happening here. The function `toggleDisplay(el)` takes an element as a parameter.

`<button onclick=toggleDisplay( <your element goes here> )>`

Now the element that we are passing has a `style` object that we can access and make changes to. You can reference that here [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp).

Edit 2: Here's another solution that attaches an event to elements in an HTML class list. The events toggle the current element's direct sibling element. You can use this with any number of different combinations that you might need it for. This way you won't need any inline JavaScript in your HTML and you won't have to insert each element individually.

Myself and most other people would recommend trying out jQuery for this kind of DOM traversing and event handling. The DOM is absolutely terrible in terms of browser compatibility and the headache involved with traversal. jQuery solves a lot of that headache.

```js
// this returns a list of your buttons with the class name 'toggle-button'
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')

// here we iterate over them to individually modify 
for (var i = 0; i <= buttons.length-1; i++){

    // here we take the current button and we add an event listener to it
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(){

            // 'this' refers to buttons[i] that we are targeting with our event
            var el = this.nextElementSibling // nextElementSibling is the ul

            el.style.display === 'none' ? // Is it invisible?
            el.style.display = 'block' :  // Then use this
            el.style.display = 'none'     // If not then use this

    })  

}
```

```html
<button class="toggle-button"> +Menu 1</button>
<ul id="dd0" style="display:none;">
    <li><a href="#">item 1:1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 1:2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 1:3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 1:4</a></li>
</ul>
<button class="toggle-button"> +Menu 1</button>
<ul id="dd1" style="display:none;">
    <li><a href="#">item 2:1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2:2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2:3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2:4</a></li>
</ul>
<button class="toggle-button"> +Menu 1</button>
<ul id="dd2" style="display:none;">
    <li><a href="#">item 3:1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3:2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3:3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3:4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This solution seems really interesting, i will look more on it tonight! Big thanks for your time!

Comment: With that code i still have to have dd,dd1,dd2 etc right? is there a way to make it so that i only need to have dd? so that it get really easy to expand if i would like to have like dd7,dd8,dd9 etc? so that it can check automatically wich "dd" it gonna display when i click corresponding link? if you get how i mean?

Comment: I've added something that is slightly more dynamic, and it doesn't involve putting in all of the id's or inline functions.

Answer (score 1):

### A CSS only solution to your current problem

The problem your are currently trying to solve can be achieved without the use of javascript at all, and would most likely be a cleaner and more scalable solution in the end.

#### The theory:

We use a `div` which wraps the menu elements, and whenever this is hovered (the `:hover` property), we show the menu. We can even add a nice little animation to this if we care.

```html
<style>
    div.menuopener{
      display: block;
    }
    ul.submenu {
      /*display: none; USE THIS IN STEAD TO LOOK LIKE YOUR EXAMPLE*/
      
      /* All of this is to make it look nice, and is not needed: */
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-transition: max-height 0.8s;
      -moz-transition: max-height 0.8s;
      transition: max-height 0.8s;
    }
    
    /*Here we select all elements of class menuopener when it is hovered, and then
     select the sub element ul of class submenu and apply styles to it */
    .menuopener:hover ul.submenu{
      /*display: block; USE THIS IN STEAD TO LOOK LIKE YOUR EXAMPLE*/

      /* max-height is just for the transition, and not needed*/
      max-height: 200px;
    }
</style>

<div class="menuopener"> 
  <p>Menu 1</p>
  <ul class="submenu" >
    <li><a href="#">item 1:1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 1:2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 1:3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 1:4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="menuopener"> 
  <p>Menu 2</p>
  <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="#">item 2:1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2:2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2:3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2:4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="menuopener"> 
  <p>Menu 3</p>
  <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="#">item 3:1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3:2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3:3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3:4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="menuopener"> 
  <p>Menu 4</p>
  <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="#">item 4:1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 4:2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 4:3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 4:4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps a bit. It might not be the perfect solution, but it should clean up your current situation and provide a much smaller, and easier to maintain, codebase.

*I do understand that what you are after is to learn javascript, but there are other, more fun, opportunities to do this other than opening menus, like https://projecteuler.net/ or https://www.codingame.com/*

Comment: I do see one problem with my solution, and that is that it does not use Javascript, which you state that you want to learn, thus maybe breaking with the underlying intent you are actually having. Can I recommend https://projecteuler.net/ for the pure programming challange purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You could use JQuery,

```
<a class="menu1" href="#"> +Menu 1</a>
<ul id="dd" style="display:none;">
    <li><a href="#">item 1:1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 1:2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 1:3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 1:4</a></li>
</ul>
<a class="menu2" href="#"> +Menu 2</a>
<ul id="dd2" style="display:none;">
    <li><a href="#">item 2:1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2:2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2:3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2:4</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here's the JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu1").toggle(function() {
            function() {$("#dd").css("display", "block");},
            function() {$("#dd").css("display", "none");}
    });
    $(".menu2").toggle(function() {
            function() {$("#dd2").css("display", "block");},
            function() {$("#dd2").css("display", "none");}
    });
});
```